# Are $\sin x$, $\sin(x + \frac{\pi}{6})$, and $\sin(x + \frac{\pi}{3})$ linearly independent?

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry, function-spaces

I'm specifically interested in the dimensionality of the subspace spanned by $\{\sin x, \sin(x + \frac{\pi}{6}), \sin(x + \frac{\pi}{3})\}$ in $C^0(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$, the vector space of continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

I think the answer is, yes, they are linearly independent, but I'm not confident about the best way to demonstrate this. Would a good approach be to do Taylor expansions at $x_0 \in \{0, \frac{\pi}{6}, \frac{\pi}{3}\}$, and examine the polynomial coefficients? This seems messy. Wondering if there's a simpler way to think about this.

Comment: Do you know that the set $\{ \sin x, \cos x \}$ is linearly independent?  If so, prove linear independence of your set directly from the definition by using trig identities to convert the latter two elements of your set to a linear combination of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$.  If you don't already know that, it's not hard to prove.

Answer (score 7):

Using the expansion of $\sin(a+b)$ we get:

\begin{eqnarray*}\sin\left(x+\frac\pi 6\right)&=&\sin x \cos\frac\pi6+\cos x \sin\frac\pi6\\&=&\frac{\sqrt{3}}2\sin(x)+\frac12\cos x\end{eqnarray*}

\begin{eqnarray*}\sin\left(x+\frac\pi 3\right)&=&\sin x \cos\frac\pi3+\cos x \sin\frac\pi3\\&=&\frac{1}2\sin(x)+\frac{\sqrt{3}}2\cos x\end{eqnarray*}

Thus $$\sqrt{3}\sin\left(x+\frac\pi 6\right)-\sin\left(x+\frac\pi 3\right)=\sin(x)$$

Comment: holy smokes. well done. i thought there was an identity like this, for $sin(a + b)$, but it's been years since i've had a reason to think of such an identity.

Comment: @grisaitis If this or any of the other answers is satisfactory, you should accept one so that this post does not get bumped by to the front page unnecessarily in the future.

Comment: thanks @CameronWilliams :) accepted another answer.

Comment: @grisaitis The answer you accepted is wrong for the reasons set forth in the comments to that answer.  It does not suffice to show that the functions are the same at three different values of $x$.

Comment: Thanks Robert. Corrected.

Answer (score 2):

First, note that $\{ \sin x, \cos x \}$ is linearly independent.  Let $f(x)= A \sin x + B \cos x$ with $B \neq 0$.  Then $f(x)= \sqrt {A^2+B^2} \sin (x+ \theta)$ for $\theta= \dfrac{B}{\vert B \vert} \cos^{-1} \left ( \dfrac{A}{\sqrt {A^2+B^2}}\right )$, which is not the $0$ function, and if $B=0, f(x)=A \sin x,$ which is only the zero function if also $A=0$.

Now use angle-addition formulas to convert $\sin (x+ \frac {\pi}{6})$ and $\sin (x + \frac{\pi}{3})$ to a linear combination of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$.  Since $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ span a subspace of dimension $2$ and we have just shown that your set of three functions lies within that subspace, your set cannot be linearly independent.

Answer (score 1):

Your functions are linearly dependent. To see this, it suffices to prove that $e^{ix} , e^{i(x+ \pi/6)}, e^{i(x+ \pi/3)}$ are linearly dependent over $\mathbb{R}$. Taking imaginary parts will solve your problem.

We need to find real numbers $A,B,C \neq 0$ such that

\begin{align*}
0 & = Ae^{ix} + Be^{i(x+ \pi/6)} + Ce^{i(x+ \pi/3)} \\
 & = e^{ix} ( A + e^{i\pi/6}B + e^{i\pi/3}C ) 
\end{align*}

Since $e^{ix}\neq 0$ for any $x$, we must find $A,B,C$ such that $A + e^{i\pi/6}B + e^{i\pi/3}C = 0$. 
Here's one way we can do this:

Pick any $C$. Then, choose $B$ so that  $\text{Im}(e^{i\pi/6}B + e^{i\pi/3}C) =0$. In other words, choose $B$ so that $e^{i\pi/6}B + e^{i\pi/3}C$ is real. Then choose $A$ to be the negative of that so that the entire sum is $0$.

Comment: would i be considering only the real part of this then, i guess?

Comment: I edited for clarity. And you would want to take imaginary parts. But taking real parts would give you a similar result for $\cos(x)$.