# Under what conditions is $\{f(x + a_i)\}$ a linearly independent set, for $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and distinct, real $a_i, i = 1,..., k$?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, independence

I'm interested in linear independence of vector spaces whose bases are functions. One instance is when a function is transposed by a scalar. For example, I asked in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4256882/are-sin-x-sinx-frac-pi6-and-sinx-frac-pi3-linearly) whether $\{\sin x, \sin(x + \frac{\pi}{6}), \sin(x + \frac{\pi}{3})\}$ is a linearly independent set of functions.

In general, for a function $f \in C^0(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$, are there any conditions or lemmas I should be aware of for showing that $\{f(x + a_i)\}$ is linearly independent for distinct $a_i$?

Comment: There won't be any general conditions that will give you anything interesting here: the $a_i$ (and thus the linear algebra tag) is a red herring, since continuous functions can do all sorts of non-sense.

Comment: I think the more interesting result is that orthogonal functions are linearly independent. Very easy to prove, and very useful as well

Comment: For orthogonal functions, do they require the notion of an inner product defined in the function space?

Comment: Also thanks Don... though I think the notion of linear independence is relevant to linear algebra?

Comment: Yes, you need an inner product, so working in $\mathbb R$ might be a bit painful. If you want to try the orthogonal polynomial approach, I'd suggest restricting the domain to something like [a,b].

Comment: You certainly need to rule out constant functions for $f$.